# Excel - Find text in value, not formula

Tags: excel, powershell

In my excel document, column A in all worksheets has a formula `(=IF(AND(D34<>"",C34=""),"Needs Price","")`. I want to use Powershell to find all cells that have the result `"Needs Price"`, but my search right now is pulling up every cell since `"Needs Price"` is in the formula.
How do I search the cells for the value, not the formula?

```vb
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

$workSheet = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(6)
$WorkSheet.Name

$Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find('Needs Price')

$BeginAddress = $Found.Address(0,0,1,1)
$BeginAddress

[pscustomobject]@{
    WorkSheet = $Worksheet.Name
    Column = $Found.Column
    Row =$Found.Row
    Text = $Found.Text
    Address = $BeginAddress
}
```

Comment: The `Find` method has the `LookIn` property that can be either *xlValues* or *xlFormulas*. Excel remembers the setting last used and employs that setting when `Find` is called without this argument (and a few others) even if the use was manual. Therefore you should always specify all arguments in the code call unless they were set by a previous call without a chance in the interim for the user to change the settings. Obviously, your result uses `LookIn:=xlFormulas` and that needs to be changed.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! $Found = $WorkSheet.Cells.Find($SearchString,[Type]::Missing,-4163)